# Query and sort by relevance

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have multiple conditions in a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE name LIKE '%text%' AND group_id = 10 LIMIT 1
```

The WHERE statements consist of 3 conditions:

- Text match
- Match of a foreign key

What if I want to sort the result by relevance, so depending on:

1. How exact the text is matched
2. How much conditions are met at all (e.g. the text match *and* the foreign key)

This is two questions in one but I think some times these will be in handy in combination. By this I'm referring to a question arising from a former post of mine ([Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339715)).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To know how exactly the text is matched, you need the [`fuzzystrmatch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) PostgreSQL module. It provides functions as `difference` and `levenshtein` that will give you an estimation of the similarity between two strings.

Then, you can build your query with some conditions like:

```sql
    SELECT *
      FROM image
     WHERE name LIKE '%text%' 
       AND ( group_id = 10 
             OR second_field = 4
             OR thirth_field = 5
           )
    ORDER BY ( (group_id=10)::int
               + (second_field=4)::int
               + (thirth_field=5)::int
             ) * weight_1
             + (strlen(name) - levenshtein('text',name)) * weight_2
```

You can adjust `weight_1` and `weight_2` to give preference to the text distance or the number of conditions met.

Comment: +1 But to avoid what I consider the `case` verbosity I would sum the booleans itseft like `(group_id=10)::int + ...`

Comment: True, it will be more concise with this kind of expression

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks @oscar-perez! Maybe it would be good to edit your answer so it also includes the suggestion of @Clodoaldo

Comment: Is it also possible to add the calculated relevance to the resultset in an easy way (without repeating the expression)?

Comment: @nepa: I'm not sure, but maybe you could move the relevance calculation to just after the * (something like SELECT  (...), IMAGE.* FROM...) and use a GROUP BY 1