# LIMIT optimized queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, lazy-evaluation, postgresql-performance

Recently I'm getting familiar with Clojure and I am amused with an idea of lazy sequence evaluation which compute values only when it is necessary.

I work a lot with PostgreSQL DB and I experienced different performance of queries when LIMIT clause is used. For example query

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT id FROM foo1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT id FROM foo2) AS subquery
LIMIT 50
```

will have the same execution time like

```
SELECT id FROM foo1
INTERSECT
SELECT id FROM foo2.
```

This suggests that Postgres firstly evaluates the whole result and then just get first 50 rows. This behaviour is in opposite to the idea of laziness, because DB process data that it is not required to get final answer. But on the other hand query

```
SELECT * FROM foo1 INNER JOIN foo2 ON foo1.id=foo2.id LIMIT 50
```

performs much better than

```
SELECT * FROM foo1 INNER JOIN foo2 ON foo1.id=foo2.id.
```

Does somebody know which Postgres operations supports such LIMIT laziness?

Comment: Note: `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` makes little or no sense.

Comment: For questions concerning query plans or performance please ***always*** include your version of Postgres and exact table definitions of your case. Read the tag info for [`[postgresql-performance]`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). Indexes and constraints are particularly relevant.

Comment: @wildplasser: As long as an *arbitrary* selection is fine, `LIMIT` can make sense without `ORDER BY`. Many newcomers are not aware of the details, though, so we see mostly incorrect queries like that in questions here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, your queries are **not equivalent** unless `id` is defined unique in both tables. `INTERSECT` handles duplicates differently from `INNER` or `OUTER JOIN`. The missing key word **`ALL`** makes the difference even bigger. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-INTERSECT)

> The result of `INTERSECT` does not contain any duplicate rows unless the
>   `ALL` option is specified. With `ALL`, a row that has `m` duplicates in the
>   left table and `n` duplicates in the right table will appear `min(m,n)`
>   times in the result set.

Joins on the other hand produce a Cartesian product, that is `m*n` rows for matching duplicates. So the query plans cannot use the same code path.

To get results that differ less (but **still not equivalent** except for unique `id`), use instead:

```
SELECT id FROM foo1
INTERSECT ALL  -- don't fold dupes
SELECT id FROM foo2
LIMIT 50;

SELECT * FROM foo1 JOIN foo2 USING (id) LIMIT 50; -- return single id column
```

Here is [a fiddle to play with](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/29595/1) (pg 9.3.1). The version on sqlfiddle.com is pretty outdated by now. Rather test with the latest version yourself.

*A lot* more time and smarts went into optimization of joins which are more commonly used by several orders of magnitude. I hardly ever use `INTERSECT`, because it often yields inferior query plans. In a quick test on pg 9.3 I could only get sequential scans out of `INTERSECT` where joins use much faster index scans. I wouldn't know of any news concerning `INTERSECT` in pg 9.4.

There would be potential for improvement, especially where unique indexes are involved. I guess nobody cared enough to work on it much since `INTERSECT` is not as popular as other operations.

I do know of very nice use cases for `UNION ALL` in combination with `LIMIT` to benefit from "lazy evaluation", though:

- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339715/way-to-try-multiple-selects-till-a-result-is-available/14365613#14365613)