# Select first record if none match

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

In PostgreSQL, I would like to select a row based on some criteria, but if no row matches the criteria, I would like to return the first row. The table actually contains an ordinal column, so the task should be easier (the first row is the one with ordinal 0). For example:

```
SELECT street, zip, city
FROM address
WHERE street LIKE 'Test%' OR ord = 0
LIMIT 1;
```

But in this case, there is no way to guarantee the order of the records that match, and I have nothing to order them by. What would be the way to do this using a single `SELECT` statement?

Comment: You just need to set up `ORDER BY street LIKE 'Test%' DESC, ord = 0 DESC`. You can remove the `WHERE` clause too, if there is always an `ord = 0` row.

Comment: @pozs: Good point - except when `street` can be NULL (which is a common case in address data). I wrote more in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to select a row based on some criteria, but if no row
>   matches the criteria, I would like to return the first row

### Shorter (and correct)

You don't actually need a `WHERE` clause *at all*:

```
SELECT street, zip, city
FROM   address
ORDER  BY street !~~ 'Test%', ord
LIMIT  1;
```

`!~~` is just the Postgres operator for `NOT LIKE`. You can use either. Note that by inverting the logic (`NOT LIKE` instead of `LIKE`), we can now use default `ASC`sort order and NULLs sort last, which may be important. Read on.

This is shorter (but not necessarily faster). It is also subtly different (more reliable) than the [currently accepted answer by @Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754014/939860).

When **sorting by a `boolean` expression** you must understand how it works:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)

The currently accepted answer uses `ORDER BY <boolean expression> DESC`, which would sort NULLs first. In such a case you should typically add `NULLS LAST`:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

If `street` is defined `NOT NULL` this is obviously irrelevant, but that has *not* been defined in the question. (*Always* provide the table definition.) The currently accepted answer avoids the problem by excluding NULL values in the `WHERE` clause.

Some other RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, ..) don't have a proper `boolean` type like Postgres, so we often see incorrect advice from people coming from those products.

Your current query (as well as the currently accepted answer) *need* the `WHERE` clause - or at least `NULLS LAST`. With the different expression in `ORDER BY` neither is necessary.

**More importantly**, yet, if multiple rows have a matching `street` (which is to be expected), the returned row would be arbitrary and could change between calls - generally an undesirable effect. This query picks the row with the smallest `ord` to break ties and produces a stable result.

This form is also more flexible in that it does not rely on the existence of a row with `ord = 0`. Instead, the row with the smallest `ord` is picked either way.

### Faster with index

(And still correct.)
For big tables, the following index would radically improve performance of this query:

```
CREATE INDEX address_street_pattern_ops_idx ON address(street text_pattern_ops);
```

Detailed explanation:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Depending on undefined details it may pay to add more columns to the index.
The fastest query using this index:

```
(
SELECT street, zip, city
FROM   address
WHERE  street LIKE 'Test%'
ORDER  BY ord  -- or something else?
-- LIMIT 1  -- you *could* add LIMIT 1 in each leg
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT street, zip, city
FROM   address
ORDER  BY ord
-- LIMIT 1  -- .. but that's not improving anything in *this* case
)
LIMIT  1
```

BTW, this is a *single* statement.

This is more verbose, but allows for a simpler query plan. The second `SELECT` of the `UNION ALL` is never executed if the first `SELECT` produces enough rows (in our case: 1). If you test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, you'll see `(never executed)` in the query plan.

Details:

- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339715/way-to-try-multiple-selects-till-a-result-is-available/14365613#14365613)

#### Evaluation of `UNION ALL`

In reply to Gordon's comment. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)

> Multiple `UNION` operators in the same `SELECT` statement are evaluated
>   **left to right**, unless otherwise indicated by parentheses.

Bold emphasis mine.
And `LIMIT` makes Postgres stop evaluating as soon as enough rows are found. That's why you see `(never executed)` in the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

If you add an outer `ORDER BY` before the final `LIMIT` this optimization is not possible. Then *all* rows have to be collected to see which might sort first.

Comment: Erwin . . . In Postgres, I don't sort by booleans (that was a MySQL-ism that crept in), so I changed that even before reading your answer.  I added an edit to the post acknowledging your point.  As usual, I learned something from your answer.

Comment: Does Postgres really guarantee that the first subquery of a `UNION ALL` is executed before the second *and* that there is a short-circuit?  I have tried researching this in other databases and wasn't able to find a trail of documentation (I agree that it might happen in practice; I'm wondering about a guarantee).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Good question (might be a fully fledged question, actually). I added a paragraph with a quote from the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've always been curious why these are not processed in parallel; I imagine that the Postgres approach is somehow implied by the standard.

Comment: Like I said, the code I provided is an example. The actual criteria is user defined, so it could be anything, really. But as always, your answer provides invaluable details which help me to optimize my query.

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right track.  Just add an `order by`:

```
SELECT street, zip, city
FROM address
WHERE street LIKE 'Test%' OR ord = 0
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN street LIKE 'Test%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Or, alternately:

```
ORDER BY ord DESC
```

Either of these will put the `ord = 0` row last.

EDIT:

Erwin brings up a good point that from the perspective of index usage, an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause is not the best approach.  I would modify my answer to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT street, zip, city
       FROM address
       WHERE street LIKE 'Test%'
       LIMIT 1
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT street, zip, city
       FROM address
       WHERE ord = 0
       LIMIT 1
      )
     ) t
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN street LIKE 'Test%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This allows the query to make use of two indexes (`street` and `ord`).  Note that this is really only because the `LIKE` pattern does not start with a wildcard.  If the `LIKE` pattern starts with a wildcard, then this form of the query would still do a full table scan.

Comment: Of course... by ordinal descending... stupid of me not to see that. :-)

Comment: Pretty poor for *all* of us not to see that. Well played @Gordon.

Comment: @amcdermott: I am not so fond of this answer, which fails to point out a couple of hidden problems. I added another answer.

Comment: Your answer now addresses the NULL issue. But either query still returns an arbitrary pick from multiple matches. The added 2nd query is needlessly complex and *expensive*. The outer `ORDER BY` makes it impossible for the query planner to optimize the query. Both SELECTs are always executed, even if not necessary. If you strip the noise, you'll arrive at my second query.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this... (I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL so syntax might be slightly off)

```
SELECT street, zip, city, 1 as SortOrder
FROM address
WHERE street LIKE 'Test%' 
-- 
union all
--
SELECT street, zip, city, 2 as SortOrder
FROM address
WHERE ord = 0
ORDER BY SortOrder
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: UNION ALL suggested (if you haven't decided to remove duplicates.)

Comment: Fair point - also, you could have this as an inline table and just select street, zip and city to avoid including the ``SortOrder` column in your results.

Comment: If you strip the added `SortOrder` and the `ORDER BY`, you lose nothing and gain performance. I explain some more in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT street, zip, city
FROM address
WHERE (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM address WHERE street LIKE 'Test%') AND street LIKE 'Test%') OR 
      (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM address  WHERE street LIKE 'Test%') AND ord = 0)
```